# printf a selected numbers in an array

Tags: c

in my program the user enters an array and the pc generates a random array (with the max number picked from user) and then the program creates a third array that shows the number from the first array that are not in the second . however i only want to type the numbers once each but the program types them again and again until array is full .

for example if i entered 0 3 1 and generated number was 1 5 9 it would print 0 3 3

i want to print 0 3 only .
full code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#define N 7
void input(int ar1[N]);
void max(int* mx);
int input2(int ar2[N], int mx);
int input3(int ar3[N], int ar1[N], int ar2[N]);

int main()
{
    int ar1[N], mx, ar2[N], ar3[N], i;
    input(ar1);
    max(&mx);
    input2(ar2, mx);
    input3(ar3, ar1, ar2);
    printf("array1 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", ar1[0], ar1[1], ar1[2], ar1[3], ar1[4], ar1[5], ar1[6]);
    printf("array2 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", ar2[0], ar2[1], ar2[2], ar2[3], ar2[4], ar2[5], ar2[6]);
    printf("array3 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", ar3[0], ar3[1], ar3[2], ar3[3], ar3[4], ar3[5], ar3[6]);
}

void input(int ar1[N])
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter 7 numbers: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &ar1[i]);
}

void max(int* mx)
{
    printf("Enter random number bigger than 0 :- ");
    scanf("%d", mx);
    if (mx < 0)
    {
        printf("you have entered a number smaller than 0 please enter a number bigger than 0 :-");
        scanf("%d", mx);
    }
    return mx;
}

int input2(int ar2[N], int mx)
{
    int i;
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        ar2[i] = 0 + rand() % (mx - 0 + 1);
        printf("%d ", ar2[i]);
    }
    return ar2;
}

int input3(int ar3[N], int ar1[N], int ar2[N])
{
    int i, j, a = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (ar1[i] != ar2[0] && ar1[i] != ar2[1] && ar1[i] != ar2[2] && ar1[i] != ar2[3] && ar1[i] != ar2[4] && ar1[i] != ar2[5] && ar1[i] != ar2[6])
            a = ar1[i];
        ar3[i] = a;
    }
    return ar3;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You wrote that you enter `0 3 1`, but your code reads 7 numbers.

Comment: The function prototype `int max(int mx);` does not match the declaration `int max(int* mx)`. Your function `input3` should return an `int`, but `ar3` is `int *`. You have some errors in your code which should be at least a compile time warning.

Comment: @mch ya that was just a short example .

Comment: @mch you sure ? cause it was working last time i tried it.

Comment: I am sure: http://codepad.org/j0MSdr6Q Also if you enter not enough numbers the rest of the array will be uninitialized and reading this values is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mch i fixed the function prototype . its weird but i was working fine even with the mistake .

Comment: @mch just tried it again it works on my compiler no errors shown.what compiler do you use ? i use visual studio 2017.

Comment: You have to enable the warnings. You can also use an online compiler like the one from my link above.

Comment: The code you posted generates **11 compiler warnings** from MSVC 2015 compiled from console, and there would be more if I hadn't suppressed the warnings which encourage the use of `scanf_s` etc.

Comment: ok so i played with the setting and found out that its been set to lvl 3 so i set it to unable all warnings and treat warning as an erorr and ran the program again.  this was the only error i got.
Error C2220 warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

Comment: ok i changed the code and used codepad now it does not display any error/warnings.you can see the new code in the post above (i updated it)

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The posted code causes the compiler to output several warning messages, several of which are very serious.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the posted code is missing several needed `#include` statements for : srand(), rand(), time(), I.E. `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <time.h>`

Comment: this function: `void max(int* mx)` says that it does not return anything. However, the function contains the statement: `return mx;`

Comment: the function: `void max(int* mx)` has the poorly written statement: `if (mx< 0)`  However, `mx` is a pointer, so is never less than 0/   Maybe you meant: `if( *mx < 0 )`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in function: `max()`, some of the testing and repeated code can be eliminated by 1) passing a parameter with type `unsigned *` rather than `int`  then writing the call to `scanf()` like so: `if( 1 != scanf( "%u", mx ) ) { perror( "scanf failed" ); }`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 4) honor the width of a printed page, I.E. on lines like: `    printf("array3 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", ar3[0], ar3[1], ar3[2], ar3[3], ar3[4], ar3[5], ar3[6]);` place the second, etc parameters on following lines, indented from the `printf` text

Comment: the function: `srand()` should only be called once in any execution of the program,  In general, this means place that call near the beginning of the `main()` function.   Note: 0 is not NULL, so this line: `srand(time(0));` would be much better written as: `srand( (unsigned) time( NULL ) );`

Comment: this line: `int ar1[N], mx, ar2[N], ar3[N], i;` contains the unused variable `i`

Comment: the function: `input2()`  is returning a pointer, but the signature says it returns an int.  However the caller of that function ignores the returned value.  Suggest changing the signature to: `void input2( int ar2[N], int mx )`  and removing the `return ar2;` statement.

Comment: the function: `input3()` is returning a pointer, but the signature says it returns an int.  However, the caller of that function ignores the returned value.  Suggest changing the signature to: `void input3(int ar3[N], int ar1[N], int ar2[N])` and removing the `return ar3;` statement

Comment: this line: `int i, j, a = 0;` contains an unused variable `j`.

Comment: @user3629249 Hello, sorry for all these mistakes as i am still new . could you tell me how do i use these -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  -Wconversion -std=gnu11 ? and what i understand now that each function should match the type of the returned value unless it is void in this case there should not be a return value? and if i am comparing a value of a pointer i should write (*mx > 0) not (mx > 0) if you have a good site that explains pointers correctly pls share :) as i dont quite get pointers .thanks again :)

Comment: @Drat018,    Here is how to use `gcc` with parameters.  `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11 myFile.c -o myFile -I.`   There are lots more possible options.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html for a list of valid options (this has a 'next' clickable link at the bottom of the page to explanations of those options.   However, in the 'working set' of options, you (usually) only need to know a few of them.

Comment: I well remember when I first worked with pointers (back when I was programming in fortran) they were, at that time, very confusing to me.  Here is a link to a page that attempts to explain pointers in C: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-pointers-fundamentals/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. handles the problems exposed in the comments to the question
2. cleanly compiles
3. has some 'appropriate' horizontal spacing added for readability

caveat:  I have not verified that the OPs posted logic is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 7

// prototypes
void input ( int ar1[N] );
void max   ( unsigned* mx );
void input2( int ar2[N], int mx );
void input3( int ar3[N], int ar1[N], int ar2[N] );


int main( void )
{
    int ar1[N];
    int mx;
    int ar2[N];
    int ar3[N];

    srand( (unsigned)time(0) );

    input( ar1 );
    max( (unsigned*)&mx );

    input2( ar2, mx );

    input3( ar3, ar1, ar2 );

    printf( "array1 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
            ar1[0], ar1[1], ar1[2], ar1[3], ar1[4], ar1[5], ar1[6] );
    printf( "array2 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
            ar2[0], ar2[1], ar2[2], ar2[3], ar2[4], ar2[5], ar2[6] );
    printf( "array3 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
            ar3[0], ar3[1], ar3[2], ar3[3], ar3[4], ar3[5], ar3[6] );
} // end function: main


void input( int ar1[N] )
{
    printf( "Enter 7 numbers: " );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &ar1[i]) )
        {
            perror( "scanf failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
} // end function: input


void max( unsigned* mx )
{
    printf("Enter random number bigger than 0 :- ");

    if( 1 != scanf("%u", mx) )
    {
        perror( "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
} // end function: max


void input2( int ar2[N], int mx )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        ar2[i] = 0 + rand() % (mx - 0 + 1);
        printf("%d ", ar2[i]);
    }
} // end function: input2


void input3( int ar3[N], int ar1[N], int ar2[N] )
{
    int a = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(    ar1[i] != ar2[0]
            && ar1[i] != ar2[1]
            && ar1[i] != ar2[2]
            && ar1[i] != ar2[3]
            && ar1[i] != ar2[4]
            && ar1[i] != ar2[5]
            && ar1[i] != ar2[6] )
            a = ar1[i];

        ar3[i] = a;
    }
} // end function: input3
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC your problem can be reduced to removing duplicates from the array. I tried to fix it and hope that it works for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N 7

void input(int ar1[N]);

int max(int * mx);

int input2(int ar2[N], int mx);
static int compact(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    int last = 0;
    assert(size >= 0);
    if (size <= 0)
        return size;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] != array[last])
            array[++last] = array[i];
    }
    return(last + 1);
}
int i, a = 0;
int j = 0;
static void print(int *array, int size, const char *tag, const char *name)
{
    int k;
    printf("%s\n", tag);
    for (k = 0; k < i-j; k++)
        printf("%s[%d] = %d\n", name, k, array[k]);
}

int * input3(int ar3[N], int ar1[N], int ar2[N]);

int main() {
    int ar1[N], mx, ar2[N], ar3[N], i;
    input(ar1);
    max(&mx);
    input2(ar2, mx);
    input3(ar3, ar1, ar2);
    int a_size = sizeof(ar3) / sizeof(ar3[0]);
    a_size = compact(ar3, a_size);
    print(ar3, a_size, "\nAnswer:", "a");
    printf("array1 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", ar1[0], ar1[1], ar1[2], ar1[3], ar1[4], ar1[5], ar1[6]);
    printf("array2 = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", ar2[0], ar2[1], ar2[2], ar2[3], ar2[4], ar2[5], ar2[6]);
}

void input(int ar1[N]) {
    int i;
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &ar1[i]);
}

int max(int *mx) {
    printf("Enter random number bigger than 0 :- ");
    scanf("%d", mx);
    if (mx < 0) {
        printf("you have entered a number smaller than 0 please enter a number bigger than 0 :-");
        scanf("%d", mx);
    }
    return * mx;
}

int input2(int ar2[N], int mx) {
    int i;
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        ar2[i] = 0 + rand() % (mx - 0 + 1);
        printf("%d ", ar2[i]);
    }
    return * ar2;
}

int * input3(int ar3[N], int ar1[N], int ar2[N]) {

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (ar1[i] != ar2[0] && ar1[i] != ar2[1] && ar1[i] != ar2[2] && ar1[i] != ar2[3] && ar1[i] != ar2[4] &&
            ar1[i] != ar2[5] && ar1[i] != ar2[6]) {
            //a = ar1[i];
            ar3[i-j] = ar1[i];
        }
        else {
            ++j;
            continue;
        }

    }
    return ar3;
}
```

Test

```
Enter 7 numbers: 2 4 6 8 9 11 12
Enter random number bigger than 0 :- 12
3 12 1 6 2 8 9 
Answer:
a[0] = 4
a[1] = 11
array1 = 2 4 6 8 9 11 12
array2 = 3 12 1 6 2 8 9
```